# es modules resolution in nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs, es6-modules

I have two nestjs modules AModule and BModule with services and constants.

In the AModule -> AService I import ASchemaKey like `import { ASchemaKy } from '../const';`
and use it in constructor

```
import { ASchemaKey } from '../const';

export class AService {
 constructor(@InjectModel(ASchemaKey) private model) {}
}
```

In the BModule -> BService I import AService in constructor

```
export class BService {
 constructor(private aService: AService) {}
}
```

and got the error `Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (?). Please make sure that the argument undefinedModel at index [0] is available in the AModule context`.

By debugging I figured out that BService file executes earlier than AService file and all imports from which AService depends like ASchemaKey is undefined

It's regarded to all things that may be imported from AModule, like
`import { ASchemaKey } from '@aModule/const'` and ASchemaKey will be undefined because of order of files execution

Is it possible to fix somehow?

My tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    
    "paths": {
      "@user/*": ["src/user/*"],
      "@auth/*": ["src/auth/*"],
      "@payment/*": ["src/payment/*"],
      "@config/*": ["src/config/*"],
      "@settings/*": ["src/settings/*"],
      "@common/*": ["src/common/*"]
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Honestly that sounds like there may be a circular dependency somewhere between the file imports.

Comment: Yes, but it's very weird behavior. All imports from "A" file will be undefined just because of "B" file executes earlier than A and interpreter doesn't know anything about A file thus marks it as undefined as I understood

Comment: Yes, that's what happens when you have a circular dependency and the modules are loaded in the wrong order. Remove the dependency cycle and it'll work

Comment: Resolved, Circular dependency was in a quite deep and unexpected place. Unfortunately nestjs doesn't show such file dependencies as angular does. The Problem was in index.ts which I imported...
Debugging source code of modules to find out where it crashes very fun (not) =)
Thanks for help =)